# Invoke Selenium within SoapUI?

Tags: selenium, soapui

I have been tasked at work to test some web services. 
I have been using SOAPUI to test web services before and also SELENIUM to do some webUI testing. 
My current task involve testing some oauth services. Basically I need to be able to go through the oauth authentication using SELENIUM and store the access token produced and pass it along my SOAPUI test to test the services. 
I have read plenty of blogs talking about integrating selenium with SOAPUI but i haven't see and guide that shows you how to do it. I am using a MacbookPro with SOAPUI 4.0.1
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I could invoke Webdriver instance in SOAP Groovy Script and assert API's with UI assertions follow below steps

Step1 : Go to your SoapUI installation directory bin/ext and drop your selenium standalone server jar files (All jars in this path will be loaded to your path , You can add any jar files in this location and call them in Groovy script steps)

C:Program Files /SmartBearSoapUI-Pro-4.6.4/bin/ext

Jar file Name : selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0

Step 2 : Create a new Project in SOAP UI

Step 3: Add New Groovy Script step

Step 4: Create your selenium driver using below script in Groovy Step (Groovy is built on Java so all JAVA libraries and code would work as such)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
    driver.get("http://www.google.com ") 
    log.info("Pagee is: " + driver.getTitle()) 
    driver.quit()
```

Step 5 : Run your script

- You might have to restart your soapui session for the first time.

If you want to verify API's in JAVA Webdriver code I would suggest you to use REST assured API

https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First step, you need to download latest `selenium-server-standalone-*.jar` and place it in `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext`; restart SoapUI.

Next you need to write your Selenium script as a [Groovy script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scripts+and+Classes) in a [Groovy Step](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-scripts.html): no class declaration. So something like:

```
def chromeDriverBinary = new File("selenium/bin/windows/googlechrome/32bit/chromedriver.exe")
assert chromeDriverBinary.canExecute()
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverBinary.canonicalPath)

def driver = new ChromeDriver()
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.get("http://www.website.test")
```

This question still has no accepted answer, so I thought I would post my own attempt, described in a blog post: http://siking.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/groovy-selenium-webdriver-and-soapui-part-3/
Maybe it will be useful to someone?